# custom layout of jsf datagrid

Tags: jsf-2, datagrid, primefaces

It is easy to use a JSF2 datagrid component to display the image for 8 entities on a page as shown below:

[image]

What i want is something that looks like this:

[image]

I have not been able to achieve this layout. Does anyone have an idea how I can proceed?

Comment: Look at [primefaces layout](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutElement.jsf) for direction

Comment: I already use primefaces. As far as I know, there is no component that helps with this stuff.